# Range of random vector

Tags: probability, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, covariance

I'm trying to prove the following statement:

let $\textbf{X}=(X_1,...,X_n)$ a random vector in $(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathcal{B}^n)$. Then $X \in  Col(C)+\mathbb{E}[\textbf{X}]$ almost surely, where $C$ is the covariance matrix of $\textbf{X}$ and $\mathbb{E}[\textbf{X}]$ is the expected value.

Here's how I should proceed:

if $C$ is invertible the thesis follows immediately,
otherwise if $C$ is non invertible then $Ker(C)$ is not trivial.

Then I should  initially prove the statement with $\mathbb{E}[\textbf{X}]=\bf{0}$ by showing that $\textbf{X}\in Col(C)=Col(C^T)=Row(C)=Ker(C)^{\perp}$, since $C$ is symmetric. I can't go on from here. I was thinking about using spectral theorem and orthogonal eigenspaces but I really don't know how to proceed.

Does anybody have any further hint to give me?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your work looks good. (assuming the statement is modified to "with prob 1").  Assuming $E[X]=0$, you just need to show that $X^Tw=0$ (with prob 1) for every $w \in Ker(C)$. You can use $C=E[XX^T]$.

Comment: Formally, the fact that $Ker(C)$ is finite dimensional (say, dimension $m$) is useful, since then the "with prob 1" implies $X$ is (with prob 1) simultaneously orthogonal to _all_ $m$ vectors $\{w_1, ..., w_m\}$ in a basis for $Ker(C)$, which then implies it is (with prob 1) simultaneously orthogonal to all vectors in $Ker(C)$.  The same would be true if the number of vectors in the basis were countably infinite, but an uncountably infinite basis might give some trouble.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think I finally came up with the solution (which I posted in the edit)

Comment: Yes, that works. My second comment above regards formally showing that if for all $v \in Ker(C)$ we have $P[X^Tv=0]=1$, then $P[\cap_{v \in Ker(C)} \{X^Tv=0\}]=1$. This is not obvious since $Ker(C)$ generally has an uncountably infinite number of vectors. [For example if $U$ is uniformly distributed over $[0,1]$ then $P[U\neq x]=1$ for all $x \in [0,1]$, but $P[\cap_{x \in [0,1]} \{U \neq x\}]=0$.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I think I finally found the way to solve my problem.

Suppose $C$ is singular and $\mathbb{E}[\textbf{X}]=\bf{0}$. Then there exists $\textbf{v} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\bf{v}\neq\bf{0}$ and $C\bf{v}=\bf{0}$.

Then $ \textbf{v}^T C \textbf{v}=0 \implies \sum_i v_i \sum_j v_j C_{ij} =0 \implies Cov(\sum_i v_i X_i,\sum_j v_j X_j)=0 \implies Var((\sum_i v_i X_i)^2)=0 \implies \mathbb{E}[(\textbf{X}^T\textbf{v})^2]=0$

The last implication holds because $Var(\textbf{X}^T\textbf{v})=\mathbb{E}[(\textbf{X}^T\textbf{v})^2]-\mathbb{E}[\textbf{X}^T\textbf{v}]^2$ and because $\mathbb{E}[\textbf{X}^T\textbf{v}]=\mathbb{E}[\textbf{v}^T\textbf{X}]=\textbf{v}^T\mathbb{E}[\textbf{X}]=0$ by hypothesis.

Then follows $(\textbf{X}^T\textbf{v})^2 = 0$ almost surely, so $\textbf{X}^T\textbf{v}=0$ almost surely.

This shows that $\forall \textbf{v} \in Ker(C)$  $ \textbf{X}^T\textbf{v}=\textbf{0}$ almost surely $\implies \textbf{X} \in Ker(C)^{\perp}=Col(C)$ almost surely (since $Ker(C)$ is finite dimensional).

If otherwise $\mathbb{E}[\textbf{X}]\neq\bf{0}$ one can take $\textbf{Y}=\textbf{X}-\mathbb{E}[\textbf{X}]$, which has the same covariance matrix as $\bf{X}$ and expected value $\bf{0}$.